# Удаление атрибута 'data-testid' из тегов HTML. Webpack. Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

Есть написанные тесты на Сepress, следуя документации Cypress лучшей практикой является ипользование кастомных атрибутов на HTML тегах таких как data-cy="something" либо data-testid="something". Но с точки зрения безопасноти, в продакшене не стоит использовать эти атрибуты. Было найдено решение в интернете по удалению аттрибутов из HTML во время сборки приложеня в продакшн. Но к сожаоению, оно не работает.

Имеется такая настройка в angular.json

```
      "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./webpack.extra.js",
          "mergeStrategies": {
            "externals": "append"
          }
        },
        ......
```

Вот непосредственно сам файл кастомного кофига WebPack, webpack.extra.js

```
let path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
 module: {
 rules: [
    {
     test: /\.html$/,
     use: ['data-cy-loader'],
    },
  ],
 },
 resolveLoader: {
 alias: {
   'data-cy-loader': path.join(__dirname, 'data-cy-loader.js'),
  },
 },
};
```

Ну и сам файл с функцией удаление атрибута по регулярному выражению - data-cy-loader.js

```
module.exports = (source) => {
var dataAttr = 'data-testid="([^"]*)"';
if (source.match(dataAttr)) {
  source = source.replace(new RegExp(dataAttr, 'g'), '');
 }
  return source;
};
```

Методом логирования всё что я узнал, так это то что resolveLoader в webpack.extra.js не отрабатывет, то есть не запускает функцию. Ангуляр в принципе находит кастомных конфиг, но не использует конфигурацию в нём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобного рода вопросов лучше давать больше информации, а именно:

- версия Angular
- какой компилятор шаблонов используется - Ivy или View Engine

Твой код не работает и не будет работать по той причине, что Angular не использует Webpack для предварительной обработки `.html` файлов.

В JITе компилятор использует трансформатор, который это:

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
```

заменяет на это:

```
template: __webpack_require__('raw-loader!./app.component.html')
```

и перед тем как код отправится в браузер, Webpack вызывает `runLoaders()`, который прогоняет контент `.html` файла через `raw-loader`, который в свою очередь превращает этот файл в псевдо-CommonJS модуль:

```
function rawLoader(source) {
  return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(source)};`
}
```

Теоретически можно было бы заменить `raw-loader` через `config.resolveLoader.alias['raw-loader'] = (путь к нашему файлу)`, и проделывать эти махинации с `.html` файлами, но как я сказал это работает только в JITе, т.е. с:

```
ng build --prod
```

это не прокатит.

Когда используется предварительная компиляция, то Angular:

- читает все `.ts` файлы
- создает из каждого файла структуру данных `SourceFile`
- если `enableIvy = true`

  - анализирует все компоненты через `ComponentDecoratorHandler`
- если `enableIvy = false`

  - анализирует компоненты через `DirectiveNormalizer`

при этом в этот же момент чтение `.html` файлов происходит напрямую через `fs.readFileSync`.

Внедриться в пайплайн компиляции невозможно в принципе, возможно пришлось бы патчить какие-то методы, но сам TS тебе этого не позволит, все узлы AST иммутабельные.

Что тебе мешает написать простой скрипт и запускать его на уровне CD, который будет проходиться по всем `.html, .ts` файлам и убирать эти атрибуты?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

const matches = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.{ts,html}'));

for (const match of matches) {
  fs.readFile(match, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (error, source) => {
    if (source.match(/data-testid=(['"])(.*)(['"])/) === null) {
      return;
    }

    fs.writeFile(match, source.replace(/data-testid=(['"])(.*)(['"])/g, ''), () => {});
  });
}
```

Comment: спасибо, буду провереять. Ангуляр 9, по умолчанию Ivy используется.

Comment: ок. С Ivy все намного сложнее, он не _extensible_, а его пайплайн не задокументирован и очень комплексный по сравнению с _VE_.

Comment: но нет ничего невозможного) отпишись потом если попробуешь скрипт

Comment: Всё отлично, работате, даже не пришлось вносить изменнеия. В pipeline запускаю перед ng build --prod. Спасибо!